# Using Twitter API's upload_with_media with iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I've been looking for a Objective-C version of [this PHP code sample](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059) on how to use Twitter's `upload_with_media` for an iPhone application.

I have been able to find one. Could you point me to ane example or explain how I could translate this code to Objective-C?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried mgtwitterengine : http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

Comment: Yes, but that does not support `upload_with_media` which is a new API method.

Comment: I don't know if you're still stuck on this but take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316776/twitters-statuses-update-with-media-on-ios-returns-500-error).

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like this for `upload_with_media`,

```
TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

            UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

            //add text
            [postRequest addMultiPartData:[@"I just found the secret level!" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withName:@"status" type:@"multipart/form-data"];
            //add image
            [postRequest addMultiPartData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) withName:@"media" type:@"multipart/form-data"];

            // Set the account used to post the tweet.
            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

            // Perform the request created above and create a handler block to handle the response.
            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
            }];
```