# Is automated sharing possible for Twitter in the background on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I wanted to share a Twitter feed on the Twitter wall which contains an image and some text. I want support from iOS 4.3 to iOS 6.0.1. Is sharing possible in the background without a send/share button? How do I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API call that you need to send is:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Before making that call, of course, you will need to authenticate with Twitter via xAuth/OAuth.  Unless you get special permission from Twitter to do otherwise, it looks like you will need to use OAuth,

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth

To background the request, it will likely make sense to use Grand Central Dispatch --that is unless you have a lot of different Twitter requests to send.  In that case, I would instead opt for an `NSOperationQueue` where `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1`.  See the following:

http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Nevertheless, because OAuth is such a pain, it will likely make sense to use a third party library.  I've never used it before, but here is an example using MGTwitterEngine:

[Twitter's statuses/update_with_media on iOS returns 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316776/twitters-statuses-update-with-media-on-ios-returns-500-error)

If you were able to limit use to iOS 5+, then I would highly recommend using the `SLRequest` object.  The advantage of this approach is that you integrate with the iOS users account directly, so they don't have to authenticate through a UIWebView or something cheesy.

To do so, you would simply plug in the appropriate Twitter API url in the following function `requestForServiceType:requestMethod:URL:parameters:` and obtain your `SLRequest` object. Then assign the appropriate Twitter `ACAccount` obtained from the `ACAccountStore` using `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:`.  Finally make your call to `performRequestWithHandler`, which would then perform your request asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you'll need find some 1.1 API wrapper (thing which generates API requests, singns them etc) for you and authoriser (MGTWitter engine works fine). I have a [working solution for sharing (text only) and getting user info for iOS 4+](https://github.com/maniak-dobrii/MDTwitterPoster).

And about background part - that depends on how you implement that (i.e. notifications or continious background execution or gps callbacs etc...).

Answer (score 2):

The following code will not post in background but it can post across ios versions...
You can use condition for ios versions like below code.This is working code I have implemented and it is working on both ios 5 and 6. Please check in ios 4 to confirm.I think it should work.

```
#import "Twitter/Twitter.h"
#import "Social/Social.h"

-(IBAction)tweetPost:(id)sender
{
 if ([self  isSocialAvailable])
 {
  SLComposeViewController *tweetComposer=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

  if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
   SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=
   ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

    [tweetComposer dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    switch(result){
     case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
     default:
     {
      NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");
     }
      break;
     case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
     {
      NSLog(@"Posted....");
      UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sent"
                                                       message:nil
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
      [alert show];
     }
      break;
    }};
   NSString*message = @"posting to twitter test ios 6";
   [tweetComposer setInitialText:message];
   [tweetComposer addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]];
   [tweetComposer addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoZ2Be2zLq8"]];

   [tweetComposer setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
   [self presentViewController:tweetComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
 }
 else
 {
  TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter= [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

  [twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]];
  [twitter addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoZ2Be2zLq8"]];
  [twitter setInitialText:@"Tweet from iOS 5 app using the Twitter framework."];

  [self presentModalViewController:twitter animated:YES];

  twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
  {
   NSString *title = @"Tweet Status";
   NSString *msg;

   if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
    msg = @"Tweet compostion was canceled.";
   else if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
    msg = @"Tweet composition completed.";

   // Show alert to see how things went...
   UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alertView show];
  };
 }
}


-(BOOL)isSocialAvailable {
 return NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil;
}
```

You need to include three frameworks named social,adSupport and Accounts.Check which one not needed with twitter feed post.
Hope ,this will help you.